# Cлайдер-карусель разезжающийся от центра к краям

Tags: jquery, javascript, плагин

Заранее извиняюсь за вопрос "не очень сюда", но может быть кто-нибудь встречал слайдер-карусель разезжающийся от центра к краям. Рою интернет уже пол дня, что-то ни как не наткнуться.

Comment: Я что-то такого слайдера не встречал. Вы имеете ввиду, чтобы картинки поочередно уходили, то вправо, то влево, когда листаешь галерею? Можете дать скрин подобного слайдера?

Comment: нет? по сути это не картинка а два блока , Например слева находится текст справа картинка.. и соответвенно левый блок уезжает влево, правый в право

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется двери http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/best-tutorials-jquery-sliding-door/